# Unable to connect to mongodb container using MongoJavaDriver

Tags: java, docker, mongo-java-driver

I can across this problem and found multiple people online with the same issue.

I had been trying:

`new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("0.0.0.0", 27017), mongoClientBuilder.build());`

I also tried `"localhost"` and `"127.0.0.1"` with no luck.
The issues raised online had the same stack trace:

```
    INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:128)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:50)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I am facing the same issue. The upvoted answer below does not help me :/

Comment: Hi @BhavyaArora. I posted an answer below which I admitted wasn't an elegant solution but worked for me. From what I can remember back then what I came up with was enough for me at the time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose the port to the docker container when you create it:

```
docker pull mongo
docker run --name mongo -d -p 27017:27017 mongo
```

and then you can connect to localhost port 27017

Answer (score -1):

First you need the container id:

`docker ps`

You need to get the specific ip for the container:

`$ docker exec -it ${container_id} bash`

This will open a terminal session within your container. Next run (in the container terminal):

`$ cat /etc/hosts`

This will print out the hosts, including an entry where the name is the first few characters of the container id.

The output will look something like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
...
...
172.17.0.2  container_id
```

The IP next to your container id is what you want to use:

`new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("172.17.0.2", 27017), mongoClientBuilder.build());`

If anyone has a more elegant solution I would be interested to hear it. For example this ip may change, though in my experience it doesn't when the container restarts.